# AWS Access issue after downgrade the instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are facing an issue to Remote Desktop login to an AWS windows instance. When we tried to login to the RDP using our user account (which is created by Admin) it is showing the error “The User Profile Service failed the login - User profile cannot be loaded”.

We also tried to regenerate the admin password from AWS admin console using “.pem” file . But when we tried to click the “Get Password” from instance listing page ,it is showing an error saying “Password not available yet:-Please wait at least 4 minutes after launching an instance before trying to retrieve the auto-generated password.” How can we solve the issue and regain the access to instance? 
If you have any idea related to this issue, it would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The password would not have changed from the random password that was assigned when the instance was first launched. So, if you remember it, just use the same password.

Of course, you can update the password through standard Windows techniques (Change Password, or joining a Domain). In this case, the original Administrator password is no longer valid.

By the way, it is recommended that after you start a new Windows instance via 'Get Password', you should change the password or attach it to a Domain as per your standard security practices. You should not use 'Get Password' as a standard security practice. It's just a way of providing you with initial access to a Windows EC2 instance.